# Buildr - put test resources on classpath

Tags: java, classpath, buildr, concordion

I'm trying to use `buildr` to build a Java project of mine. I have a bunch of concordion tests and HTML specifications, located like so:

```
src/test/java/spec/x/y/z/SomethingTest.java
src/test/resources/spec/x/y/z/Something.html
```

`buildr` finds the actual test code (`SomethingTest.java`) and runs it, but the HTML does not end up on the classpath and so the test fails. I get the following error:

```
[junit] Testcase: [Concordion Specification for 'Something'] took 0.002 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] Resource '[classpath: /x/y/z/Something.html]' not found
[junit] java.io.IOException: Resource '[classpath: /x/y/z/Something.html]' not found
[junit]     at org.concordion.internal.ClassPathSource.createInputStream(ClassPathSource.java:15)
[junit]     at org.concordion.internal.XMLSpecificationReader.readSpecification(XMLSpecificationReader.java:25)
[junit]     at org.concordion.Concordion.process(Concordion.java:30)
[junit]     at org.concordion.Concordion.process(Concordion.java:26)
[junit]     at org.concordion.internal.FixtureRunner.run(FixtureRunner.java:18)
[junit]     at org.concordion.integration.junit4.ConcordionRunner$1.evaluate(ConcordionRunner.java:113)
[junit]     at org.concordion.integration.junit4.ConcordionRunner.runChild(ConcordionRunner.java:104)
[junit]     at org.concordion.integration.junit4.ConcordionRunner.runChild(ConcordionRunner.java:18)
[junit] 
[junit] TEST x.y.z.SomethingTest FAILED
```

My `buildfile` is as follows:

```
repositories.remote = 'http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2'

JODA = 'joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0'
CONCORDION = 'org.concordion:concordion:jar:1.4.2'
XERCES = 'xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1'
XOM = 'xom:xom:jar:1.2.5'

define 'my-project' do
  project.version = '0.0.1'
  compile.with JODA
  test.with XERCES, XOM, CONCORDION
  package :jar
end
```

I have tried to force the HTML files onto the classpath using variations on `Java.classpath << 'src/test/resources/x/y/z'` and `test.resources.include` but to no avail. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you access the resource ? Does placing the html file next to the .java file resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

By default Buildr uses mavens convention of separating source code and resources. So test resources need to be put in the "src/test/resources" directory.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the correct answer. The resources folder is not picked up. You can always change the layout of your project to accomodate.

Comment: Somehow helped me on a completely gradle project and typesafe configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

be sure you're using
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream([your URL]);

and not just new File([your URL]);

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I am doing so - everything is fine inside my IDE or with Maven, it's just `buildr` that seems to be struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Buildr should in theory copy resources to `<project-dir>/target/test/resources` and include this in the classpath when running tests.  Check to see if this directory exists, and if so, if it is empty.

Are you running Eclipse while this problem occurs? If so, this could be a conflict between buildr and eclipse.  Try to shut down Eclipse, then run `buildr clean` and `buildr test`.

I've seen similar issues, and my theory is that Eclipse creates empty target directories as soon as they are deleted, for instance by Buildr. Then Buildr checks the timestamp of the target directory and sees that it is more recent than any of the source resources, and figures that it must be up-to-date.  Thus, any program that creates empty target resource directories could in theory cause this problem.